# Android: Not more than 1 nine patch image at a time?

Tags: android, xml, widget, drawable, nine-patch

I am having problems with nine patch images ( **.9.png ). I have a widget layout and would like to use nine patch images for the widget's backgroud. Here is my background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg" />
</selector>
```

The drawbales name is "appwidget_bg.9.png". This stuff works fine. But I would like to use different images for the focused and pressed states.

So I make it look like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg" />
</selector>
```

The problem: As soon as I add the additional drawable "appwidget_bg_pressed.9.png" I get the following error message:

.../res/drawable/widget_bg.xml:21: ERROR Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/appwidget_bg').

.../AndroidManifest.xml:6: ERROR Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').

It seems like I can only add one nine patch drawable to the drawables folder. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain they've been imported into your drawables folder? That error is saying it's not found the files. You can certainly have multiple 9-patch images. Seems like it's found appwidget_bg_pressed.9.png, but isn't seeing just appwidget_bg.9.png or icon.png

Comment: yeah, that's what it looks like. somehow like the new one "appwidget_bg_pressed.9.png" is blocking something... i can not figure what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I was facing same problem and I figured it out and solved my problem.

The problem was with 9-patch drawables; they had patches on one side instead of two. because I didn't want my drawable to stretch vertically but it seems that I can't do it with one side patching.

I hope it'll help others.